# Path for python is different than my .bash_profile

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

I'm working through Learn Python the Hard way, and I'm currently on exercise 46 where you learn to create packages. I've created a basic package that does a few calculations, and uses a few different modules.

I've gotten the package to install in my python2.7 site packages, but I can't seem to run the module from my site packages after the fact. I'm wondering if the path that python is searching is different, because of the following:

After the install, I see this message `Copying story-0.1-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

However, when I try to run the module, I see this message `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'story.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Sorry if this makes absolutely no sense, I'm very new to the fantastical world of programing.

Comment: How are you trying to import/run story.py? For example, what happens when you just try `import story`

Comment: I get `-bash: import: command not found`

I'm using a setup.py doc to install the package if that helps at all.

Comment: Ah, I apologize! Start a python session with `python` then try `import story`

Comment: Wow haha, I should have gotten that at this point though!

So I run python and do `import story`, and I just get a new line with a new command prompt

Comment: It appears you've got two versions of Python, and the confusion is there.

Comment: @I'L'I, is this in reference to the 2.7 in one line and the 2.7.12_1 in the other. That certainly could make things not work... What's the best course of action to fix it?

Comment: @VincentLevinger That's good! That means your package is installed correctly. Will you post the code or command that causes the `No such file or directory` error you're seeing?

Comment: @ChristopherApple, I'm just inputing `python story.py` directly into the command line

I also just tried running python, and then typing just `story`. I get a message that says `<module 'story' from 'story/__init__.pyc'>`

Comment: @VincentLevinger Ah, yep! There is your problem.  Writing up an answer now

Answer (score 0):

When you install a package, you access the internals differently. You can no longer just call `python story.py`.

To access the functions in `story.py` you need to `import` the module at the top of another python file, or in the interpreter.

If story.py contained

```
def my_test_function(blah):
    print blah
```

You would use this function in another file by the following (after installing the module, as you've already done)

```
import story

story.my_test_function("Hello!")
```

By importing the module, you get access to all the functions and classes inside it by typing `module_name.function_name`. You could also just import the function you wanted to use directly, which would look something like

```
from story import my_test_function

my_test_function("Hello!")
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Let's say then that `story` was just a series of print commands and function calls to basic math operators (plus, minus, etc).

So now, I've amended that so that `story.py` has a function called `run_story`, which runs all the print commands. I re-installed and imported story into python, and tried story.run_story, but got the same `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_story'` message :(

Comment: So I navigate to the directory where it's stored, and type `python setup.py install` into the terminal

Comment: Try `python setup.py develop` and try again. A brief explanation of this is that the `develop` automatically reloads the module when changes are made, great for development

Comment: So gave that a shot, and still no go. the `develop` command runs just fine, but I'm still unable to run my module in python. I took the liberty of printing my sys.path, and this is what the result is.

`['', '/Users/fuo213/Dropbox/Hotel Stuff/Python/projects/first', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', `